# TFS Team Build Finding generated MSI files in the sources directory

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm generating on each build MSI files which are located in my build directory in the build server those MSI files I would like to copy to my drop folder.

So i'm using a `FindMatchingFiles` activity in my XAML and put it inside a for each loop to run over the files in the **Sources** directory.
Like this: `String.Format("{0}\**\*.msi", SourcesDirectory)`

But actually I would like the search pattern to be like this: `String.Format("{0}\SpecificDir\**\*.msi", SourcesDirectory)`

But as soon as I change the original pattern it finds nothing..
How can I change this string to be customized as I want it to be?

**Another important piece of information.. those setups are vdproj files and not WIX.**

Comment: What tool are you using to build the .MSI files?

Comment: I'm using a devenv command located in a batch file which runs through an invoke process activity in the build template

Comment: That's unfortunate. One of the many shortcomings of VDPROJ is that it doesn't support MSBuild requiring you to come up with ways of building and archiving it.   WiX wouldn't require this and it uses $(OutDir) so archiving is automatic.

Comment: Yep, I know that..
Unfortunately moving to WIX isn't in our scope at the moment..
But I just don't understand why when I add another \**\ it stops working..
So weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for the issue, I created a new variable called for example: `SpecificDir` and instead of putting the `SourcesDirectory` variable in the match pattern I put the new variable `String.Format("{0}\**\*.msi", SpecificDir)` and now it starts the search from the directory hierarchy I wanted.

Unfortunately I still didn't understand why adding another directory to the match pattern doesn't work.